# Ho to get PR flow in git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

Do we have a way to get statistics from git.
Basically I want to get a report of a particular issue id, time taken to approve PR after it open with state changes.

Eg: PR-100

Open --> Need work --> Approve = 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using the [BitBucket API `/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D)

```
curl -u <username>:<password> \
 https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<username>/<repository name>/pullrequests/{PR-id}
```

The JSON answer would include:

```
created_on: string (date-time
updated_on: string (date-time)
approved: boolean
```

That will help you get started and see if, by exploring the JSON payload, you can extract what you need for your report.